# unity - adding a material to this sprite changes the sprites shape, why?

Tags: c#, sprite, glow, unity-game-engine

So i have this sprite:

[image]

but i want to add a glowing effect to it, so i add a material to it, but for some reason when i add the material. the sprite changes shape as such:

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening, i havent put any code onto this sprite so it cant be that. Can someone help me? Thank you.
Also here is a pic the details of the material:
[image]

Comment: Looks like the shader is not recognizing the alpha values correctly.

Comment: Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: This should be asked on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try to use the `Fade` Rendering mode, instead of the `Opaque` one in the properties of your material.

Comment: @Hellium Shouldn't this be an answer? If you do make it as one, let me know.